# Reset Google Credentials and upload to Google Play Store - Expo/React Native

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo, credentials

I'm using Expo/React Native. I have to upload a new version of my APK/AAB into Google Play Store. For that, I needed to reset my Google Credentials. I contacted Google Support Team and I have just sent them the new PEM file created. Which is the next step to attach the new certificate to the new builded app version?